# curl GET json API command not working

Tags: api, curl

I can't seem to get this simple curl API command to work.  The original sample code is in HTML/Javascript.  The I ran the code using Chrome and used developer tools to record the session.  The html/js example worked fine.  I copied the chrome network request URL and inserted it into the curl command with no luck.  Here is what Chrome "More tools--> Developer tools --> Network --> Headers" gave me,

```
Request URL:https://api.betterdoctor.com/2016-03-01/doctors?location=37.773,-122.413,100&skip=2&limit=10&user_key=CODE_SAMPLES_KEY_9d3608187
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:52.9.169.107:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I tried to the following curl command and just cut and pasted the chrome results,

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X GET https://api.betterdoctor.com/2016-03-01/doctors?location=37.773,-122.413,100&skip=2&limit=10&user_key=CODE_SAMPLES_KEY_9d3608187
```

I get the following error message,

```
{"meta":{"error":true,"message":"Missing user_key","error_code":1000,"http_status_code":401}}'skip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'limit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'user_key' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try wrapping the URL in quotes
`curl -k -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X GET "https://api.betterdoctor.com/2016-03-01/doctors?location=37.773,-122.413,100&skip=2&limit=10&user_key=CODE_SAMPLES_KEY_9d3608187"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `man bash`, you'll find the following paragraph:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0. Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate in turn. The return status is the exit status of the last command executed.

To avoid `bash` interpreting this operator, you should put quotes around your URL to make it a string literal:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X GET "https://api.betterdoctor.com/2016-03-01/doctors?location=37.773,-122.413,100&skip=2&limit=10&user_key=CODE_SAMPLES_KEY_9d3608187"
```

Comment: You are correct!  I placed quotes around the https and it worked perfectly.  Good explanation...